# Video tag within the 3djs

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to add a html5 video to 3dsjs Force

This is the JavaScript code:

```
nodeEnter.append("svg:image")
             .attr("class", "roundimage")          

            //.attr("xlink:href",      "http://www.xxxxxxx.com/img/people/profilevedranm.jpg")
            .attr("xlink:href", function (imageLocation, i) {
                return imageLocation.image;
            })
            .attr("x", "-8px")
            .attr("cursor","pointer")
            .attr("y", "-8px")
            .attr("title", function (title) {
                debugger;
                if (title.id === "basevideo") {
                    //alert("Do we have a handle");

                    nodeEnter.append("svg:video")
                            .attr("width", "320")
                            .attr("height", "240")
                            .attr("autoplay", "")
                            .append("source")
                            .attr("source","video/hrewego.mp4")
                            .attr("type", "video/mp4");
```

This renders the following HTML:

```
<g class="node" transform="translate(551.5633729425251,297.6744384520498)">
<image class="roundimage" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 xlink:href="/img/Logo.png" x="-8px"
       cursor="pointer" y="-8px" title="An Vivid Company" id="Maa Tech" width="96px" 
height="80px"></image>
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay="">
    <source source="video/heythere.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
<text class="nodetext" dx="15" dy=".35em"></text>
</g>
```

It creates as far as I can tell proper video element, but it will not play. Even when I remove the image tag, the element is not rendered at all.

Is there some special way of "injecting" an video SVG element on to the page? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG 1.1 does not have a `<video>` tag so most UAs don't support `<video>` in SVG.

If you want video in SVG your best bet is to wrap it in a `<foreignObject>` tag. Don't forget to give the foreignObject width and height attributes.

Comment: I found the example here: http://s3.amazonaws.com/trms-dev/svg_video_test/example.html. But it will not render video in my case. Could it be because I used Force layout???

Comment: Did you use Force layout?

Comment: I just went to the link in the comment.

Comment: Oh I got that working on my side as well. However it seems that force is not working properly. I will experiment more